# User Data Not Saving To Firebase (Username, first name, Last Name)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store data in my Firebase database but the app crashes when I call the function saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(). The performRegister() function works fine which stores the email and password using FirebaseAuth but when I call performRegister() then saveUserToFirebaseDatabase() right under it, the performRegister() doesn't execute all the way though. performRegister() is suppose to make a log.d tag which tells the uid and that it successfully stored the email and password. It does that but when I call saveUserToFirebaseDatabase() under performRegister() in the onCreate function, it doesn't log the uid like it did without the saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(). Instead the performRegister() Log displays the username and passowrd then skips to the saveUserToFirebaseDatabase() which logs display the username, first name, and last name from the previous activities the user had to enter when signing up for the account. Then it crashes. Here is my code. I want to be able to call performRegister() then saveUserToFirebaseDatabase() to save the user's email and password using FirebaseAuth then save the user's other information in the database using saveUserToFirebaseDatabase().

```
class Password_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var editPasswordText: EditText
    lateinit var editConfirmPasswordText: EditText
    lateinit var btnOpenActivity: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password)

        editPasswordText = findViewById(R.id.edit_password)
        editConfirmPasswordText = findViewById(R.id.edit_confirm_password)
        btnOpenActivity = findViewById(R.id.password_continue_btn)




//        btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=false

        val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                var passwordinput: String = editPasswordText.text.toString().trim()
                var confirmpasswordinput: String = editConfirmPasswordText.text.toString().trim()
                btnOpenActivity.isEnabled = passwordinput.isNotEmpty() && confirmpasswordinput.isNotEmpty()


            }
        }


        editPasswordText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        editConfirmPasswordText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)


//        var intent = intent
//        val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")
//        val firstname = intent.getStringExtra("firstname")
//        val lastname = intent.getStringExtra("lastname")
//        val emailaddress = intent.getStringExtra("emailaddress")




        val btnOpenActivity: Button = findViewById(R.id.password_continue_btn)
        btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener {


            performRegister()
            saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()



//            val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity_welcome_after_signup_dashboard::class.java)
//            startActivity(intent)
//            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left)
        }
    }
// Save user's email and password 
    private fun performRegister(){
        var intent = intent
        val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
        val password = editPasswordText.text.toString().trim()

        if (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        Log.d("SignUpActivity","Email is "+ email)
        Log.d("SignUpActivity","Password is $password")

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("SignUp", "Account creation unsuccessful")
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }

                //else if successful
                Log.d("SignUp", "Successfully created user with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("SignUp", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
            }

    }
// Save user's username, first name, and last name to database
    private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(){
        var intent = intent
        val username = intent.getStringExtra("username")
        val firstname = intent.getStringExtra("firstname")
        val lastname = intent.getStringExtra("lastname")
        Log.d("Signup","Storing user information in password activity: $username, $firstname, $lastname")

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")

        val user = User(uid, username, firstname, lastname)
        ref.setValue(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("Signup","We saved the user to Firebase Database")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("Signup", "Failed to save user to Firebase Database")
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }

    }


//Animation for back button
    override fun finish() {
        super.finish()
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right)
    }
}

data class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val firstname: String, val lastname: String)
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `performRegister` call happens aysnc in the background. This is why `saveUserToFirebaseDatabase` is getting called before it completes. Instead, just call it when `performRegister` is complete in the `onCompleteListener`.

Change this:

```
btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener {
    performRegister()
    saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()
}
```

To:

```
btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener {
    performRegister()
}
```

and add `saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()` to:

```
      .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("SignUp", "Account creation unsuccessful")
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }

                //else if successful
                saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()
                Log.d("SignUp", "Successfully created user with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
            }
```

Comment: It saves the saves the email and password  to user authentication but the app still crashes. I think the problem of has to do with the way saveUserToFirebaseDatabase() is written. None of the fields first name, last name, and username are written to the database users part in Firebase

Comment: Ok so after the Log.d("Signup","Storing user information in password activity: $username, $firstname, $lastname") in saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(), the app crashes